# Django path error - No module named models

Tags: django, url, import, view, models

I have an import error in a Django app, I guess it's pretty simple but I can't figure it out…

It's a simple notepad app, called «notes» with 2 models, «note» & «category». To clean things up, I wanted to seperate each models views & urls, so here is what I get:

`/notes

    admin.py

    forms.py

    models.py

    /urls

        category.py

        note.py

    /views

        category.py

        note.py`

The problem is that my views don't find the models, here is the Traceback - http://dpaste.com/hold/539425/ and parts of the code: http://dpaste.com/hold/539416/

I didn't mention the **_*init*_**.py files in the above snippet, but I double-checked all of them…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code pastie says `from notes.models import Category, Note` but your traceback says `from models import Category, Note`. It's hard to tell if those are the same line because you're only pasting snippets. Still, it should be 'from notes.models import foo' always.

Are you sure you're always referencing the `notes` app in your `models` import?

UPDATE:

If you're using the correct `from foo.models import bar` syntax, then my next thoughts are that you've possibly got a circular dependency that's stopping Python importing things from the models file.

But the traceback implies the notes/models.py can't be found. So... when you say you double-checked the **init**.py files, that doesn't mean they're right. :p There should be one in notes/ and also in notes/urls/ -- they don't have to contain anything.

Comment: Yep, sorry, in a desperate attempt I tried with only « models » and I copied this traceback but it's `from notes.models import Category, Note`.

Comment: I've just re-checked the __init__.py files, which seems ok but in another desperate attempt, I deleted all .pyc and it seems to work fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
from notes.models import Category, Note
```

Comment: Same as @stevejalim, in a desperate attempt I tried with only « models » and I copied this traceback but it's `from notes.models import Category, Note`